# SQL Server Stored Procedure Increment max of varchar column and return output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output

This my table `D_Demande` with `idDemande` column of type `varchar(10)`:

[image]

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_maxIdDemande] 
    @maxidDemande varchar(10) output
AS
BEGIN
    declare @numDemande varchar(10)
    declare @currentDemandeDate varchar
    declare @currentnum varchar
    declare @num varchar

    select @numDemande = max([idDemande]) from [dbo].[D_DEMANDE]

    IF (@numDemande is null)
        BEGIN
            select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+'0001'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @currentDemandeDate = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,0,7)
            set @currentnum = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,7,4)
                IF(FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy') = @currentDemandeDate)
                    BEGIN
                        set @num = CAST(@currentnum as int) + 1
                        select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+@num
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+'0001'
                    END
        END
Return
END
```

The problem that I get 0 when I debug those two statements:

```
set @currentDemandeDate = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,0,7)
set @currentnum = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,7,4)
```

Can you help with this?

Comment: storing date as varchar(10) is not recommended. are the rows mentioned above only rows in your table? what is the value of `select  max([idDemande]) from [dbo].[D_DEMANDE]`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise, you end up with a variable of **1 character** length - usually *not* what you want ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your variable declaration

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_maxIdDemande] 

    @maxidDemande varchar(10) output
AS
BEGIN

    declare @numDemande varchar(10)
    declare @currentDemandeDate varchar   --<-- This is declared as VARCHAR(1)
    declare @currentnum varchar           --<-- This is also declared as VARCHAR(1)
    declare @num varchar                  --<--and this one too
```

You need to explicitly define the length of the varchar variable , otherwise it uses the default value of `1`

It should be

```
declare @numDemande         varchar(10)
declare @currentDemandeDate varchar(10)
declare @currentnum         varchar(10)
declare @num                varchar(10)
```

### Procedure Definition

A fixed version of your proc would look something like...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_maxIdDemande] 
    @maxidDemande varchar(10) output
AS
BEGIN
    declare @numDemande         varchar(10)
    declare @currentDemandeDate varchar(10)
    declare @currentnum         varchar(10)
    declare @num                varchar(10)

    select @numDemande = max([idDemande]) from [dbo].[D_DEMANDE]


IF (@numDemande is null)
    BEGIN
        select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+'0001'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @currentDemandeDate = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,0,7)
        set @currentnum = SUBSTRING(@numDemande,7,4)
            IF(FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy') = @currentDemandeDate)
                BEGIN
                    set @num = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(CAST(@currentnum as int) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)),4)
                    select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+@num
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    select @maxidDemande = FORMAT(getdate(),'ddMMyy')+'0001'
                END
    END
END
```

### Execute Proc

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(10);
EXEC [dbo].[get_maxIdDemande] @output OUTPUT
SELECT @output
```

With current data in the table it should output value `0704150002`